# Using RegExp to get a series of words which may or may not have spaces before and after

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a series of text after a colon (:) character, while ignoring the whitespace characters before and after.

example

```
someWord: a series of text
-or-
someWord:        a series of text
```

I would like to get the result of 'a series of text', ignoring any whitespace after the colon, but including whitespace within the text phrase.

My attempts at coming up with the regexp for this have failed, hoping the SO community can help!

Here is my bad regexp (I apologize in advance for what you are about to see):

```
:[^ ](\w*)+?(?=\b)
```

Comment: Just match it with `:(.*)` and then trim.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/sP5wJ0/1

Comment: or, Split on colon and get the last element and trim.

Comment: Yeah, everything depends on what this series of text is.

Comment: You could use `\:\s*(.*)$` and then grab the group with index 1 from the match

Comment: Do you have just *one* of these to match, or several within the same string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you only have one of these you're matching (not several in the string; see my question on the question), then I think you're looking for

```
:\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

- `:` matches the colon
- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace chars (greedy)
- `(...)` is the capture group for the target text
- `.*?` is a non-greedy capture of any series of characters
- `\s*$` is a greedy capture at the end for whitespace

```js
var s1 = "someWord:     a series of text    ";
var match = /:\s*(.*?)\s*$/.exec(s1);
log("Input: '" + s1 + "'");
log("Result: '" + match[1] + "'");

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('pre');
  p.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(msg)
  );
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Imagine what might happen if the input string has no linebreaks and is some megabytes long. Lazy matching will most likely cause a timeout issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It's always possible to imagine all kinds of things. Since there's nothing in the question suggesting that, it's irrelevant speculation.

Comment: I just want to point out that this approach is inefficient in JavaScript.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Well, first, I don't blindly accept your premise. But more importantly, premature optimization is exactly that: Premature.

Comment: Just tried it: On a ~20MB string with the target text somewhere after the first ~5MB, took 129ms to do the match for V8 in Node on my Core i5 3.3GHz machine (resulting match string was ~15MB). (How old am I that I wrote MHz first and had to backspace?!)

Answer (score 2):

```
> "someWord: a series of text".match(/:\s*(.*)$/)
[": a series of text", "a series of text"]
```

To get the text you can use the 1st index referring to the captured group and for the spaces at the end of string you can use trim():

```
> "someWord:        a series of text  ".match(/:\s*(.*)$/)[1].trim()
"a series of text"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, you could use [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```js
document.write("someWord: a series of text".split(':')[1].trim());
document.write('<br>'); // just to insert a new line for printing
document.write("someWord:        a series of text".split(':')[1].trim());
```